# WPF: Style based on another one in a separate assembly

Tags: wpf, resources, styles, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

Assembly A - ResourceDictionary contains StyleA style. 
Assembly B - ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries to merge resources from Assembly A into B.

I would like to create a style in Assembly B "based on" StyleA. Is it possible?

I am trying to create this style:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleB" BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleA}">
   <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="Khaki"/>
</Style>
```

But I get a XamlParseException exception at run-time, if I use StyleB:

***Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Style' to object of type 'System.Windows.Style'. Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type 'IFrameworkInputElement'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' in markup file 'SamSeekApp;component/mainwindow.xaml'***

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try adding TargetType="{x:Type Button}" to your 'StyleB'.

Comment: Thanks Richard. It works! But why doesn't it work without specifying the type?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure why it is needed here.

Comment: Because WPF needs to know what type your style is targeting, so it can check the properties, etc you override.  Even if the parent (BasedOn) style declares the target type, you still need to redeclare the target type in the child style

Comment: this is awesome :-)

Comment: note this also work when defining a style 'in place' for a control, which you may need to do to set DataTriggers on it