# Cannot base style on another style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have some locally defined styles within `Window.Resources`. I have some styles for a `TextBlock`, `TextBox`, `CheckBox` and `RadioButton`. These are supposed to be applied to all controls in the window, so I haven't provided a value for `x:Key`. I would like them to inherit from a style targeting `FrameworkElement`. So I have something like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    ...
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
   ...
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    ...
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    ...
</Style>

<Style x:Key="TriggerBase" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Style.Triggers>                
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            ...
        </Trigger>                
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

My problem is that I am unable to set the `BasedOn` property to inherit from my `TriggerBase` style. After looking at similar questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703206/wpf-style-based-on-another-one-in-a-separate-assembly) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675004/base-a-style-on-another-style-in-a-resource-dictionary), I still cannot get it working. These answers suggest you need to specify the `TargetType` on your base style, which I have done.

I thought maybe the Styles have to target the exact same type, but after digging around on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I found that wasn't the problem:

> If you create a style with a TargetType property and base it on another style that also defines a TargetType property, the target type of the derived style must be the same as or be derived from the type of the base style.

If I set `BasedOn` like `BasedOn="{DynamicResource TriggerBase}"`, it can find my `TriggerBase`, but I get an error stating:

> A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'BasedOn' property
>   of type 'Style'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a
>   DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

If I try `BasedOn="{StaticResource TriggerBase}"`, I get an error that it cannot find `TriggerBase`. One of the linked answers above showed using `StaticResource` like `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}`, but it still cannot resolve the style.

How can I inherit from the `TriggerBase` style? I'm targeting .NET 4.5.

Comment: Just tried your code and the only thing I had to do is move `TriggerBase` style to the top and then `BasedOn="{StaticResource TriggerBase}"` worked

Comment: That worked, thanks. I didn't realise the ordering was important. Lesson learned. I'll accept your answer if you want to add it as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct and you can base your styles on `FrameworkElement` style just need to move

```
<Style x:Key="TriggerBase" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">

</Style>
```

to the top and then

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TriggerBase}">
```

will work